# WHM S3 backups using private IP with reduced costs betwen aws ec2 and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, whm

Two months ago I created an EC2 instance with WHM - Centos 7 from the marketplace.
For back-up configuration I have used S3 which is running perfectly.
My current daily back-ups have around 10GB in size which would total to some 50 GB bandwidth transfer per month.
Now, from what I've read https://www.apptio.com/blog/aws-data-transfer-costs/ the transfer between services within a certain region should be free if one uses a private IP.
Currently, the transfer is from the WHM instance ( with required public Elastic IP) to S3, using the WHM built in S3 backup functionality, and is generating the folowing costs:

```
$0.000 per GB - data transfer in per month4.640 GB | $0.00
$0.000 per GB - first 1 GB of data transferred out per month1.000 GB | $0.00
$0.010 per GB - regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using elastic IPs or ELB0.005 GB | $0.00
$0.090 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer out beyond the global free tier54.730 GB | $4.93
```

How could I take advantage of the within region free transfer for storing my whm back-ups?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are your "daily back-ups" created as Amazon EBS Snapshots? Why do you think that these charges are related to your backups?

Comment: No. They are WHM backups for cPanel accounts done by WHM Back-up configuration feature/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `data transfer in` refers to traffic coming into the VPC from the Internet. For example, somebody using your application or uploading data. It is not used for your backups. It has no charge.
- `data transfer out` refers to traffic going from the VPC to the Internet. For example, return data going to somebody using your application (or even you accessing your instances via SSH). It is not used for your backups.
- `regional data transfer` is traffic going between AZs, or traffic going out of the VPC to a public IP address and back in again. It is not used for your backups.

If you are using Amazon EBS Snapshots for backup, then the backups will not trigger any of these costs.

If you are sending backup data to Amazon S3 from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region, then the backups will not trigger any of these costs.

It would appear that the costs are related **application usage** rather than the backups.

Comment: The backups are saved on the server by WHM, then they are immediately transferred to S3 using the WHM save to S3 functionality.
Both the EC2 instance and S3 bucket are in the same region, though charges are being applied as can be seen in the invoice details.

Comment: **No charges are being applied as a result of the EC2 instance copying data to S3.** The charges shown are for **Data Transfer**, which is when traffic goes _to the Internet_ or _from the Internet_. This would either be people using your apps, or you connecting into your app (eg SSH, RDP), or the app retrieving data from the Internet.